# How can I open a new terminal and execute a rosrun command through a cpp program?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need a code example

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252421/how-can-i-open-a-new-terminal-and-execute-a-rosrun-command-through-a-cpp-program-?/) by [bill](https://answers.ros.org/users/29021/bill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Not recommended

To run any shell commands from a cpp program, you can use the `std::system` function. ie

```
#include <cstdlib>  // I think 'system' is in here?

int main(void) {
    std::system("rosrun [package] [node]");  // replace [package] and [node] with the relevant text

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This won't work unless the master node is running (i.e you have called `roscore` or `roslaunch` first)

### Recommended

Normally when you want to start a node, you run all the nodes you'll need in the program using a [launch file](http://answers.ros.org/question/12216/launch-file-how-to-write-it/).  Instead of generating new nodes during runtime, you could also create [services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services). The [Cpp API](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp) gives you basically all the interfaces you'll need.

I would highly recommend doing the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). They take ages, but go a long way to understanding ROS.

Also, before posting a question next time, [look](https://www.google.co.nz/search?channel=fs&q=open+a+rosnode+in+cpp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9SqBWKahI8_r8Af9_7_wDQ) [for](http://answers.ros.org/question/223090/start-or-stop-the-ros-node-in-another-node/) [the](http://answers.ros.org/question/12260/terminate-launch-other-node-from-code/) [answer](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/how-to-run-a-node-from-another-node-td2439377.html) [first](http://answers.ros.org/question/208574/using-rosnodes-api-c/), and if these don't answer your question, follow the [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support). A more descriptive title might be "How to execute rosrun command from cpp", then the informal text can go in the text body.

---

Originally posted by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) with karma: 186 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bill](https://answers.ros.org/users/29021/bill/) on 2017-01-23**:
thanks you so much ,and i promise that next time i will consider what you wrote and then i will ask something

**Comment by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) on 2017-01-23**:
No problem, hopefully the tutorials are able to kickstart your project!